# subdomains and url rewrite

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

Good morning, i have a problem and i don't find a solution.
I need to point multiple domain to same folder but my hosting when i create a subdomain point to a folder with the same name of the subdomain.

The result that i want to have is:

`demo.domainname.tld/index.php` will point  to `www.domainname.tld/shop/index.php?username=demo`
`demo.domainname.tld/product.php?id=100` will point to `www.domainname.tld/shop/product.php?id=100&username=demo`

`test.domainname.tld/index.php` will point  to `www.domainname.tld/shop/index.php?username=test`
`test.domainname.tld/product.php?id=100` will point to `www.domainname.tld/shop/product.php?id=100&username=test`

keeping in the url the subdomain address.

I am creating a ecommerce platform and i want to use an unique ecommerce and load different content by keeping the username from subdomain.

it is possible? how?

Answer (score 0):

A long as all the `*.domainname.tld` DNS entries point to the same IP as `www.domainname.tld` and they all share the same document root, you can add these rules to the htaccess in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domainname\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /shop/index.php?username=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domainname\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?product.php$ /shop/product.php?username=%1 [L,QSA]
```

If you want to actually do a redirect, thus changing the URL in the browser's address bar, include a `R` flag in the square brackets so they look like: `[L,QSA,R]` or `[L,QSA,R=301]` for a permanent redirect.

Comment: when i create a subdomain the folder is created out of the www root then i can not use your rewrite rules?

Comment: @user1739269 Then you need to place these rules in the root of the subdomain.

Comment: i have tryied and say like this:Not Found

The requested URL /shop/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: @user1739269 then you either need to alias `/shop` from all of your subdomains, or proxy, but including `http://www.domainname.tld` in front of the `/shop/` targets and add a `P` to the square brackets

Comment: i have made like this but still give me error: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domainname\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ http://www.domainname.tld/shop/index.php?username=%1 [L,QSA,P]

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /shop/index.php?username=demo was not found on this server.

Comment: @user1739269 probably because you don't have mod_proxy loaded, I'm assuming since you don't have control over things like that (you can't even change your site root), you're probably out of luck.

Comment: forgetting the subdomains, how i can make like facebook to give an address like this www.domainname.tld/username/nameoffile?variables to load content from www.domainnames.tld/shop/nomefile?variables? many thanks

Comment: @user1739269 without mod_rewrite, you're not going to be able to do it

Comment: how i can check if i have it? there is a way? if for you is not a problem add me to skype my nick is abalest14 we can talk easy. many thanks

Comment: @user1739269 you should call your hosting company's customer service

Comment: i was opening a ticket and the reply was that the mod_rewrite is active but must to put on the htaccess this two parameters RewriteEngine e RewriteBase otherwise will not function. for rewriteengine is ON and for rewritebase? i remember that the subdomain forled is out of the root like this /subdomain/www/ thanks again